# Try to recover from an error with TouchXML

Tags: iphone, libxml2, touchxml

I'm trying to make an XPath query with [TouchXML](http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/wiki/TouchXML), but if the query fail, the programm crash immmediately.

Is there any way to prevent this and continue the execution of the programme.

I know that TouchXML is based on [libxml2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) and that lib have an option called `XML_PARSE_RECOVER` but i don't know how to use it with TouchXML.

Source code

```
- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)d
{
    if (![super init])
        return nil;
    NSError *error;

    translation = [[WRTranslation alloc] init];
    parser = [[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:d options:0 error:&error];

    if (error)
      NSLog(@"initWithData error = true");

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"dealloc de WRTouchParser = %@", self);
    [translation release];
    [parser release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL)queryData:(NSString *)s
{
    // Nécessaire pour faire une requête. Exemple : //x:div[@class="se"]
    NSDictionary *mappings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" forKey:@"x"];
    NSArray *res = [parser nodesForXPath:s namespaceMappings:mappings error:nil];

    queryResult = [res description];

    return YES; 
}
```

I try to make a wrong XPath query like that : //x:div[@cla

And I get :

```
XPath error : Invalid predicate
```

Comment: Can you post the code you're using and the details of the crash? I haven't used TouchXML but it sounds like something's wrong if it's crashing.

Comment: It's only if I execute a wrong XPath query : like `//x:div[@cla`

Answer (score 1):

i am using a normal

```
@try {
    ...
} @catch (NSException *e) {
    ...
}
```